# How to show in grafana's status panel a sum of two measurements from influxdb

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I need to show in Grafana in a status panel (plugin) the sum of two different measurements:
in_bytes + out_bytes

Preferably the last data.

Any idea/hack how to overcome as I know there is no join in influxdb and I can't prepare on the server-side the data (merge and write to influx one measurement which sums them)?

Comment: There's a Grafana plugin called MetaQueries that can select the results from other queries and perform operations over them. https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/goshposh-metaqueries-datasource I suppose if you write to queries that fetch data from different measuements and then write a 3rd meta-query which sums the first two ... do tell if that works! I've been meaning to try it out.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know about this. Meanwhile, I decided to change the data, instead of two different measurements, to use two fields under the same measurement.